# Delay between multiple Supervisor processes executions

Tags: supervisord

I have multiple PHP workers and I need to set delay between startup each of them. How to handle it?

*Start 1 process / Wait 20 secs / Start 2nd process / Wait 20 secs ...*
Keep 50 proccesses alive at same time.

```
[program:get_comments]
directory=/var/www/
command=/usr/bin/php post_request.php
user=root
autostart=true
autorestart=true
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
numprocs=50
stdout_logfile=/var/www/worker.log
stderr_logfile=/var/www/worker.error
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where, starting 64 python rq-worker processes using supervisorctl was raising CPU and RAM alert at every restart. What I did was the following:

```
command=/bin/bash -c "sleep %(process_num)02d && virtualenv/bin/python3 manage.py rqworker --name %(program_name)s_my-rq-worker_%(process_num)02d default low"
```

Basically, before running the python command, I sleep for N second, where N is the process number, which basically means I supervisor will start one rq-worker process every second.

In your case, the following should works:

```
command=/bin/bash -c "sleep $((%(process_num)01d + 20)) && /usr/bin/php post_request.php"
```

Please note that the first process will start after 20 sec as well.